# How can I tell what processes are causing high loads if they are not high-cpu usage?

Tags: linux

Sometimes my servers will show a high load average in the "top" program (e.g. load is ~10 on a 4-core machine), but the actual CPU usage isn't particularly high.

I assume the issue is that there are many I/O-intensive jobs running. Is there any easy way to identify these jobs that are causing the load, if their "%CPU" values in top aren't that high?

Comment: Could you paste the summary area that you see when you run the `top` command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`iostat` can report statistics like that. Usually included in your distro in the package sysstat.

[dstat](http://packages.debian.org/sid/dstat) might also be worth a look, it's a modern replacement.

Answer (score 9):

To find what's causing high load you can check few things.

- `vmstat -w` will show you ovierwiem (processes, swap, mem, cpu, io, system)
- `pmstat -P ALL`  will provide you statistics (with %iowait) per cpu core
- `iostat -x` look for high %util or long await or big average queue size

  - dig deeper with `iotop`
- `ps -ax` look for state D which is uninterruptible sleep (usually IO), run it one more time check if they are still in D state

  - dig deeper with strace
  - check files and connections of those processes with lsof and netstat
- sar/sysstat - with that tool you can explore not just "now" stats but also check what was happening yestarday at midnight

  - `sar -b` - overall io activities
  - `sar -d` - individual block device io activities

Comment: I found `ps -ax | grep " D "` particularly useful, since it clearly shows whats "hanging".

Answer (score 4):

If you have [IO accounting](http://ipozgaj.blogspot.com/2008/09/linux-io-accounting.html) in your kernel, then you can use `iotop` to give information like that. Also, monitoring tools like collectd can record and report on the data.